# Build React Native project after pulling from GitHub

Tags: xcode, git, github, react-native

My friend initialized a GitHub repo after initializing React Native in a certain directory. After I pull his files into a directory and initialize a local repository on my computer and run the XCode project, there seem to be a lot of missing files and the build fails. There's probably something I need to do which is taken care of when setting up react native in the "react-native init AwesomeProject" step, but I'm not trying to set up a new project. Instead, I want to keep the files he's already developed, but set up the React Native "environment"..how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you checked the .gitignore to see if the node modules folder was ignored? If so, you may need to do an npm install.

Comment: Not sure how to interpret .gitignores, but I see the following in the file:
# node.js
#
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **install the dependencies** through npm. Just enter the following command in the root directory of your project:

```
npm i
```